# Rails 5 - Modify devise views but new fields don't save to db

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am adding the fields user_name and job_function to a user model created with Devise.  I am able to add the fields to the view, but the two new fields are not saved to the database.  Only :email and :password are saved which is what was already happening.

*****UPDATE:

I'm getting the following error:
 Unpermitted parameters: user_name, job_function

So I'm looking at getting around that.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Thank in advance.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_action :authenticate_user!
            :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:user_name, 
    :job_function)}
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:user_name, 
    :job_function)}
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:update) { |u| u.permit(:user_name, 
    :job_function)}
  end
end
```

views/devise/registrations/new.html

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :job_function %><br />
    <%= f.radio_button :job_function, 'EMT' %> EMT
    <%= f.radio_button :job_function, 'Paramedic' %> Paramedic
    <%= f.radio_button :job_function, 'Fire' %> Fire
    <%= f.radio_button :job_function, 'Nursing' %> Nursing
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170429200947) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "location_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "body"
    t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_articles_on_location_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_articles_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "location_name"
    t.string   "location_address"
    t.string   "location_description"
    t.float    "lat"
    t.float    "lng"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "job_function"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "articles", "locations"
  add_foreign_key "articles", "users"
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  root 'homes#index'
  get '/locations', to: 'locations#index', as: 'locations'
  get '/locations/new', to: 'locations#new', as: 'new_location'
  get '/locations/splash', to: 'locations#splash', as: 'splash'
    #  Location Routes

  get '/locations/map', to: 'locations#map', as: 'map'
  post '/locations', to: 'locations#create'
  get '/locations/:id', to: 'locations#show', as: 'location'
  get '/locations/:id/edit', to: 'locations#edit', as: 'edit_location'
  patch '/locations/:id', to: 'locations#update'
  delete '/locations/:id', to: 'locations#destroy'

    # Article Routes

  get '/articles/:id/new', to: 'articles#new', as: 'new_article'
  get '/articles/:id', to: 'articles#show', as: 'article'
  get '/articles', to: 'articles#index', as: 'user_articles'
  post '/articles', to: 'articles#create'
  delete '/articles/:id', to: 'articles#destroy', as:'delete_article'
  get '/articles/:id/edit', to: 'articles#edit', as: 'edit_article'
  put '/articles/:id', to: 'articles#update'
  patch '/articles/:id', to: 'articles#update'

  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add the following to my ApplicationController:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:user_name, :job_function])
  end
```